# Looking for a color movie shown on tv

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw only a couple of minutes. Apparently a disaster sent eveyone underground. They created a genetic workforce that sort of look like Frankenstein. The ground above (desert) is ruled by mutants. I seem to remember something about sterility being an issue.

Comment: Are there *any* other details you can remember? How long ago did you see it? About how old did it look?

Comment: Yes, other details like when the movie looked like it was from (roughly) would be very helpful, also any more visual details you can remember--for example, can you describe what you mean by "sort of look like Frankenstein"? Did they have bolts in the neck, large foreheads, flat top of the head, move with lurching motions, unusual colored skin, or what?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177986/trying-to-find-a-sci-fi-movie-probably-from-the-50s-or-60s (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

Long shot, but could it be [The Time Travelers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Travelers_(1964_film)) from 1964? The movie is about some time travelers from the 20th century who travel through a time portal they've developed into the year 2071, and in this future an advanced civilization was living underground with barbarian mutants on the surface, and the underground dwellers had built androids to be their servants. The complete movie is on youtube below, you can see some shots of the mutants if you skip to 14:40 or so, and a shot of some androids at 19:20, and at 22:20 one of the underground dwellers explains the history of how the world got that way: